# Formatting of React bootstrap table search and pagination

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

How can I change the color of react-bootstrap-table following features?

1. Pagination : [image: image1]
2. Search option :[image: image2]

Comment: You really want to use react-pagination-table for pagination. Why can't you try specified pagination package for react. Because, I have checked  and came to know that there is no way for changing color for pagination  from this github issue(https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/1452). Why cannot you try react-pagination(https://github.com/vayser/react-js-pagination)

Comment: It makes easier for pagination as well as search

Answer (score 0):

You can override the CSS using these.  This are all that I have used. I'm sure there is more:

```
#pageDropDown - the id of the page size dropdown
.react-bootstrap-table-pagination-total - the class for the pagination total class (showing 10 of 500)
.react-bootstrap-table-page-btns-ul - class for pagination page numbers
```